# Computer cluster synchronization methods

Tags: synchronization, cluster-computing

Synchronizing data in a computer cluster system is an important problem these days. There are several synchronization tools available like [Csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/paper.pdf) or [Lsyncd](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lsyncd/).

**My question is:** *What are the most used synchronization algorithms?*

**What I am looking for:** *Articles and posts that describe the synchronization methods (preferably not older than 2015).*

I tried googling and eventually came up with some useful information, but I'm still on the lookout for more.

Comment: Maybe a better question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jameslarge Do you recommend deleting this one and posting a copy on the softwareengineering site?

Comment: I take it back.  I was going to refer you to the "[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" page, but after reading it myself, I'm not so sure any more.